# Apache Camel unique property name in two different routes

Tags: apache-camel

We have multiple routes running independently on a quartz scheduler, most of the functionalities are similar, so we have created some common routes to call inside parent routes for code reuse.

Is generic route property will be treated as a local variable and will not be shared among two different routes or value of the property will be changed by some other route.

```
<setProperty propertyName="remoteServerException">
    <simple>${exception.message}</simple>
</setProperty>
```

Above is one of the property used in common route, and called from multiple routes, is it fine to be called like this? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<setProperty>` is referring to `properties` on the Camel `Exchange` which is the instance, that contains the message being routed - there is one `Exchange` per message and its not shared - its local for that given message. So if you have some kind of shared route, you call via `direct` endpoints etc, then calling `<setProperty>` will not cause harm, its operating only on the `Exchange` instance.